# when i click on submit button my email is not send why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

when i click on submit button it will show me the message from the javascript file but it will not go to the php file that i have generated..

here is my html code

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" action="email_send.php">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="grid_6 alpha fll">
                <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Name *" class="requiredField" />
            </div>
            <div class="grid_6 omega flr">
                <input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Email Address *" class="requiredField email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message *" class="requiredField"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" />
    <span>  </span>
</form><!-- end form -->
```

my js file

```
if ($("#contactForm")[0]) {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
        $('#contactForm .error').remove();
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').removeClass('fielderror');
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').addClass('fieldtrue');
        $('#contactForm span strong').remove();
        var hasError = false;
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').each(function () {
            if (jQuery.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
                var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                $('#contactForm span').html('<strong>*Please fill out all fields.</strong>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if (!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                    $('#contactForm span').html('<strong>Is incorrect your email address</strong>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });
        if (!hasError) {
            $('#contactForm').slideDown('normal', function () {
                $("#contactForm #sendMessage").addClass('load-color');
                $("#contactForm #sendMessage").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("btn-success").val('Sending message. Please wait...');
            });
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), formInput, function (data) {
                $('#contactForm').slideUp("normal", function () {
                    $(this).before('<div class="notification-box notification-box-success"><p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent. We check Our email all the time.</p></div>');
                });
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

my php file which i have written on action is

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['senderName']) && isset($_POST['senderEmail']) && isset($_POST['message']) )
{

    $senderName = $_POST['senderName'];
    $senderEmail = $_POST['senderEmail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(!empty($senderName) && !empty($senderEmail) && !empty($message))
    {
        if(strlen($senderName)>25 || strlen($senderEmail)>25 || strlen($message)>50 )
        {
            echo 'Maximum length reached for each field';
        } 
        else
        {
            $to = 'info@courtpiece.com';
            $subject = 'Court Piece Rung';
            $body = "Name:".$senderName."\n"."Message: ".$message;
            $header = 'From'.$senderEmail;

            if(@mail($to,$subject,$body,$header))
            {
                echo 'Thanks for Contacting Us.We\'ll in touch soon. ';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Sorry an error occured ';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'All fields are required. ';
    }       
}
```

?>

Comment: in which place i have need this??? @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan when i click on submit button it will show me this message ">Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent. We check Our email all the time." but it will not redirect to the php file and mail will not sent.

Comment: why do you want a redirect?

Comment: @mplungjan after which line i have to place this??

Comment: @MaxBumaye no sir in action button i have written my php file name

Comment: well you dont want the form to redirect you... your $.post() calls the PHP file and gives you the result

Comment: @MaxBumaye yes sir in form tag in front of action i have give php file name in which i have written code of sending email

Comment: Forget what I said, you can replace the return false with e.preventDefault() (and add (e) to the .submit(function(e) - but there is likey something else worng too. I for example would not have `if ($("#contactForm")[0]) {` - the event handler will be attached if there is a form and not if not

Comment: @mplungjan sir there is no return false is written...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this can create a problem..
You are using: `if(isset($_POST['senderName']) && isset($_POST['senderEmail']) && isset($_POST['message']) ){`

instead of:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendMessage'])){
if(!empty($_POST['senderName']) && !empty($_POST['senderEmail'])){

CODE HERE
}
}
```

If not, then probably you miss-confiugred your email sending service.
try a test on the email sending.
`mail()`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to supress the default behaviour of your form so it doesnt also send a request to your server. You do this by calling the prevendDefault function of your event parameter .submit(function(e)....

```
if ($("#contactForm")[0]) {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //to suppress the behaviour of your Form -> you will send data manually with $.post
        $('#contactForm .error').remove();
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').removeClass('fielderror');
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').addClass('fieldtrue');
        $('#contactForm span strong').remove();
        var hasError = false;
        $('#contactForm .requiredField').each(function () {
            if (jQuery.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
                var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                $('#contactForm span').html('<strong>*Please fill out all fields.</strong>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if (!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                    $('#contactForm span').html('<strong>Is incorrect your email address</strong>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });
        if (!hasError) {
            $('#contactForm').slideDown('normal', function () {
                $("#contactForm #sendMessage").addClass('load-color');
                $("#contactForm #sendMessage").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("btn-success").val('Sending message. Please wait...');
            });
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post("email_send.php", formInput, function (data) {
                $('#contactForm').slideUp("normal", function () {
                    $(this).before('<div class="notification-box notification-box-success"><p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent. We check Our email all the time.</p></div>');
                });
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

I have to say that there is room for improvement in the way you have built up this validation. 
Try running the form again with the additions I made.

Report back!